# Two routes with multiple parameters to single controller's method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, url-routing

Let's assume I have models: `Article`, `Post`, and `Comment`. For these models I need to map `CommentsController#show` in `articles` and `posts`. Something like this:

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments, :only => [:show]
end

resources :posts do
  resources :comments, :only => [:show]
end
```

And this works perfectly, i.e. it'll generate routes something like this:

```
/articles/:article_id/comments/:id
/posts/:post_id/comments/:id
```

Both pointing to the same controller's single method: `CommentsController#show`

What I need is to include more/multiple parameters for posts while retaining the same URL routes to `CommentsController`:

```
/articles/:article_id/comments/:id
/posts/:post_id/:post_title/:post_year/comments/:id
```

I tried `match` but first occurrence at `resources :articles do...` overrides it.

```
resources :articles do
  resources :comments, :only => [:show]
end
match '/posts/:post_id/:post_title/:post_year/comments/:id', :to => 'comments#show', :as => :show_post_comments
```

It throws an error:

> No route matches {:controller=>"comments", :action=>"show",
>   :post_id=>10, :post_title=>"some title", :post_year=>"1995", :id=>"1"}

So, is it possible to create such a route with multiple parameters to single controller's method in two resources using `get` or something?

Comment: why don't you send those parameters appending them to the URL?

Comment: Because there's a JavaScript which appends the comment id at the end of the path on submit button whenever the user selects a comment and click submit. So, if there's no way to solve this then I'll have to rewrite the JavaScript to split with slashes '/' and append id before `?post_title='some title'` etc.

Comment: You can append multiple parameters to the URL, e.g., `/posts?abc=1&def=2&name=rsb`

Comment: What does `bundle exec rake routes` show for that route (the one defined with `match`)? Also, it'd be better to use `get` instead of `match`. P.S. Yes, this is possible.

Comment: @RSB - It's not for posts, it's for comments, I have something like this: `/posts/11/comments/?post_title=sss&post_year=1995` I will have to modify JavaScript to split and join this data-url from **<a href='#' data-url='....'></a>** element to generate this: `/posts/11/comments/1?post_title=sss&post_year=1995` on the basis of the selected comment's id. I hope it's clear now?

Comment: @pdobb: here is the relevant output - `show_post_comments    GET    /posts/:post_id/:post_title/:post_year/comments/:id(.:format) comments#show`

Comment: The route looks good and looks like it should match. The params look like they match up... How are you calling it? Oh... if this is a form submission then I guess it'd more likely be a `post` than a `get`... But depends on if you're setting the method of form submission.

Comment: `show_post_comments_path(:post_id => post.id, :post_title => post.title, :post_year => post.year, :id => '')` and comment's id with a default value: `show_post_comments_path(:post_id => post.id, :post_title => post.title, :post_year => post.year, :id => 1)` both don't work. So, my guess is that previously defined route with `articles` has overridden it. No, it's not a form submission. I need to redirect user to the selected comment section where they can perform other operations on a comment.

Comment: So, instead of submitting a form to some method in controller and then redirect it from the controller by forming a path, I'd prefer to save the time and do the calculation at client/browser end itself using JavaScript. Hence, my question: I needed `/:id` at last for this JavaScript to be working. And, for example's sake let's say `post.title` returns a URL like string: "some-title", this approach kinda clean. I personally don't like those ugly looking appended params in URLs.

Comment: The only thing I can think is maybe `post_title` needs to be parameterized? `:post_title => post.title.parameterize`

Comment: @pdobb - That's what I said in the previous comment: 
> for example's sake let's say post.title returns a URL like string: "some-title" i.e. parameterized string.